# How would i make a Jquery / css based table like this?

Tags: jquery, css

[image]

I want it to fade animate in and out as i roll over the rows. The row should look like one with the content panel, as though the content panel and row are merged. Hope you guys understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does principally what you want

**CSS:** Split the page into two parts, a table and a detail part (or content panel, as you call it)

```
#tableView
{
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

#detailsView
{
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#tableView tr").mouseenter(function() {
    var detail = $(this).html(); // or whatever you want to show in content pane
    $("#detailsView").html(detail).fadeIn("slow");
  }).mouseout(function() {
    $("#detailsView").fadeOut("slow");
  });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
</html>
  <body>
    <div id="tableView">
      <table>
        Your table goes here …
      </table>
    </div>

    <div id="detailsView">
      …
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this works for the most part, but im not getting the fade behavior as i roll over the rows.

Comment: @WillingLearner All right, I've update the JS. Now you shall get the fading effect.